# Find out a given word in a String using Regex in java

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Given a String,
Using **regex in java or java code** i have to find out Electors name from the given String :

```
                "K ~\n" +
                "m W swim\n" +
                "sﬁaruqsr\n" +
                "wvnn 021m: r’ i\" W' _ ~\n" +
                "_ 4'“; x ‘ D\n" +
                "W ma ¢ “ii-a? “Rm qwﬂ\n" +
                "Electors name ; Moleslwar Moreshva;\n" +
                "Tuwal\n" +
                "mam-a #02,qu _\n" +
                "F\n" +
                "Fm“ Name : Momma! Tuppal I\n" +
                "‘ e\n" +
                "Pam sq» : w! MALE '\n" +
                "“WW/Dale m mm ; XX/xxnsae _‘"
```

Like for the given String the output should be : **Moleslwar Moreshva Tuwal**

Can't hardcode anything as the String response changes everytime.
Please help:)

Comment: How does the string change, and what part of the string remains the same? Do you have a code example of what you already tried?

Comment: This string is generated by getting characters from an image.So, it doesn't remain the same. The String "Electors name" is constant.

Comment: Then how do you know `mam-a #02.....` isn't part of the name?

Comment: beacuse i also have the document from which this string is retrieved :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no name end delimiter hence will have to assume the full name needs to be captured from the line where `Electors name` is present and the next line only. And once it is captured, replace unwanted character with a space.

Here is the java code that parses the name for you,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "K ~\n" +
            "m W swim\n" +
            "sﬁaruqsr\n" +
            "wvnn 021m: r’ i\" W' _ ~\n" +
            "_ 4'“; x ‘ D\n" +
            "W ma ¢ “ii-a? “Rm qwﬂ\n" +
            "Electors name ; Moleslwar Moreshva;\n" +
            "Tuwal\n" +
            "mam-a #02,qu _\n" +
            "F\n" +
            "Fm“ Name : Momma! Tuppal I\n" +
            "‘ e\n" +
            "Pam sq» : w! MALE '\n" +
            "“WW/Dale m mm ; XX/xxnsae _‘";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Electors name\\s*;\\s*([\\w; ]+\\n\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1).replaceAll(";\\n", " "));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Didn't match");
    }
}
```

This prints following output,

```
Moleslwar Moreshva Tuwal
```

Comment: Could you please help me to get out the name when the String is :



": 43 i
Hit :
GD |
HRT Pav amar h
Ted a3 !
ZMY1960756 : y |
A : for ib
Wags v, |
EKO
fadias =r amy;
fra
Electors Name :
ANKIT |
Rar #1 am: gob aw
Father's Name: MURARI LAL
| AT 1 Sex ' i I Male
| 3 : 11/03/1990
S sFafafa/ oos ;"

Comment: The given String should display "ANKIT" as output

Comment: Your this string looks better than earlier in your post, because here at least I see a delimiter which is `|`. You can use this regex `Electors Name\\s*:\\s*([\\w ]+)\\s*\\|`

Comment: Isn't working!!

Comment: Let me update the code in answer.

Comment: @ankur: You double escaped the slashes. You just needed to use as it is. Use this Pattern line. Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Electors Name\\s*:\\s*([\\w ]+)\\s*\\|");

Comment: could you please send me the updated regex?

Comment: Use this method.  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s1 = "43 i Hit : GD | HRT Pav amar h Ted a3 ! ZMY1960756 : y | A : for ib Wags v, | EKO fadias =r amy; fra Electors Name : ANKIT | Rar #1 am: gob aw Father's Name: MURARI LAL | AT 1 Sex ' i I Male | 3 : 11/03/1990 S sFafafa/ oos ;";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Electors Name\\s*:\\s*([\\w ]+)\\s*\\|");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
  if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
  } else {
   System.out.println("Didn't match");
  }
 }

Comment: It's working!!..fine thanks!:)

Comment: @ankur43: If it worked for you, can you mark answer as accepted?

Comment: Done!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Will this regex work for both the cases? : "electors name\s*(:|;)\s*((([\w ]+)\s*\|)|([\\w; ]+\\n\\w+))"

Comment: @ankur43: No since the pattern of data in both the cases is different. You will have to use separate regex for handling both the cases.

Comment: it will give output in both the cases :  

"electors name\s*[:;]\s*(([\w; ]+\n\w+)|(([\w ]+)\s*|))"